# Querying the most commented Post in Django and django-comments-xtd

Tags: python, django

I use django-comments-xtd implementing the commenting system in my django project, I've written the following function to query the most commented post in my blog.
It works well sorted, but when I return the result to my caller, the array is unsorted.
`comment_counts` is the dictionary which contains `object_pk` and `comment_count`
How can I return the sorted posts with `Post.pusblished.filter(pk__in=post_ids)`
Here is my snippest after importing all necessary modules:-

```py
@register.simple_tag
def getMostCommentedPosts(count=5):
    content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Post) 
    comment_counts = XtdComment.objects.values('object_pk').annotate(comment_count=Count('object_pk')).order_by('-comment_count')[:count]   
    post_ids = [comment['object_pk'] for comment in comment_counts]
    return Post.published.filter(pk__in=post_ids)
```

Comment: I have never used django-comments-xtd so i can't give you exact code, but can't you do something like that Post.objects.annotate(comment_count=Count('comments')).order_by('-comment_count') ?

Comment: My model has no field named `comments`